# Is there a better regular expression patterns than my sample for a routing in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, regex, cakephp-3.x

Below is my regular expression patterns.

```
$routes->connect(
  '/:token', 
  ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index'],
  [
    '_name' => 'home',
    'token' => '([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,4})',
    'pass' => ['token'],
  ]
);
```

I want the URL to match the following pattern for the routing in CakePHP 3.

/AB1-1234-1234-12

The first block must be three characters, possible combination of letters and numbers only.
The second block must be exact four numbers.
The third block must also be exact four numbers.
The fourth block can be at least one number and max four numbers.

Each block must be concatenated by the `-` sign. I am a junior developer and believe that there is a better regular expression than this to approach the same result.

Comment: Do you need the capture groups? If not, [`[^\W_]{3}-(?:\d{4}-){2}\d{1,4}`](https://regex101.com/r/ekemsW/8) is pretty barebones.

Comment: If that works for you I can answer the question with a more detailed writeup of what exactly it does.

Comment: @emsimpson92: removing capture groups is a good idea but `(?:\d{4}-){2}` isn't very useful, adds steps and isn't shorter than `\d{4}-\d{4}-`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I suppose you're right. I was looking for a way to cut back the redundancy, but it's not really any simpler.